# Bootstrap Inline Form Layout in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, bootstrapping

I have the following code in my view file index.phtml.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('daterange'));?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('itemInterval')); ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('submit')); ?>
</div>
```

I want to have an inline form. What I want is to have on a single line all the controls. You can see in the image how look now my form: [image]

Here is my code from IncidentsForm.php:

```
     class IncidentsForm extends Form
 {
     public function __construct($name = null)
     {
         // we want to ignore the name passed
         parent::__construct('incidents');
         $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
         $this->setAttribute('class', 'form-inline');

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'daterange',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Start Time'
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'daterange',
                'class' => 'form-control'
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'name' => 'itemInterval',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Item interval',
                'options' => array( 3 => 3, 5 => 5 )
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'itemInterval',
                'class' => 'form-control'
             ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Filter',
                'id' => 'submitbutton',
                'class' => 'form-control'
            ),
        ));
     }
 }
```

Comment: you need to use in you form definition the label_attributes part, with col-XX-X depends on your medias.

Comment: Check out the zf2-twb-bundle: https://github.com/neilime/zf2-twb-bundle It's really a nice component if you want to bootstrap ZF2 forms, you simple add the module in you application config, use plain ZF2 forms and the view helper will give you a bootstrap form without any further html code or css definitions in your forms. For different types of forms like the inline-form see the documentation